# Dynamically update Beeware Toga widgets from outside the class

Tags: python, widget, beeware

In my Beeware app I did not find a way to return results to the user on android, by dynamically updating an output value in a `TextInput` box . I am looking for a way to dynamically `update the toga widgets`, in particular `text widgets`. In my search I encountered a short discussion at https://github.com/beeware/toga/discussions/1325 , from which it appears that the thing should be possible, and even easy. The discussion at the link above includes a short exemplary code, but I had no success in trying to make it work for me. I would much appreciate any clarification how to adapt that code to Beeware app, or how to update the text widgets in any other way.

**UPDATE:** I finally found out that what caused the crash in android was the keyword `refresh()` that works with windows but not with android. The following code works OK with `TextInput` on both the Beeware emulator and on my Galaxy23 phone. However does not work with `MultilineTextInput`

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW
import time
import threading

class HelloWorld(toga.App):

    def change(self,text):
        self.name_input.value=text

    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        self.name_input = toga.TextInput(value=text,style=Pack(flex=1),readonly=True)
        name_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=ROW, padding=5))
        name_box.add(self.name_input) 

        main_box.add(name_box)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

def thr():
    global text,change
    text="start text"
    time.sleep(2)
    for i in range(5):
        text="new text "+str(i)
        myApp.change(text)
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    global myApp
    myApp=HelloWorld()
    return myApp

t1=threading.Thread(target=thr,args=());t1.start()
```

Comment: As I said in your previous question, nobody can help you unless you show your code and describe exactly what happened.

Comment: @mhsmith Thank you,  you got me in the middle of uploading it. In half an hour will be ready. I will update the question accordingly

Comment: @mhsmith I finally found that what caused the crash was the keyword refresh() ). I don't really understand why, because it works well in windows. Is the code above a proper way to do it? Please see the UPDATE above. Thank you for your kind support

Comment: The only problem I can see with your code is that it accesses the UI on a background thread, which most platforms don't allow. Instead, you should use `add_background_task` with an async function, as shown [here](https://github.com/beeware/toga/blob/v0.3.1/examples/handlers/handlers/app.py#L47).